# How to remove words in pandas data frame column which match with words in another column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am trying to remove part of string in pandas data frame column which are present (matched) in another column, these values are separated by comma and could be one or more. I want to create a new column with the remaining part of string. Below is the reproducible example and my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country' : ['Germany, France, Brazil, India, Russia','Russia, France, 
   Jamaica, India, China',
                 'Germany, Russia, Jamaica','Italy, Jamaica'],
    'Exclude' : ['France, Brazil','India, Russia','Jamaica','Italy']})

print(df)
```

Printed data frame:

```
                                  Country         Exclude
0  Germany, France, Brazil, India, Russia  France, Brazil
1   Russia, France, Jamaica, India, China   India, Russia
2                Germany, Russia, Jamaica         Jamaica
3                          Italy, Jamaica           Italy
```

I want to create column "Output", which will have the names of countries which are not present in column "Exclude". So i tried:

```
df['Output'] = df['Country'].replace(to_replace=r'\b'+df['Exclude']+r'\b', 
value='',regex=True)
```

Desired Output:

```
Country                                    Exclude              Output
0  Germany, France, Brazil, India, Russia  France, Brazil       Germany, India, Russia
1  Russia, France, Jamaica, India, China   India, Russia        France, Jamaica, China
2  Germany, Russia, Jamaica                Jamaica              Germany, Russia 
3  Italy, Jamaica                          Italy                Jamaica
```

Which does the half job, like it matches when the text in "Exclude" column is exactly present in "Country" but doesn't work when the sequence is different than what is in "Exclude" column. For example it will not work on second row.
I spent a lot of time and tried few other approaches before posting the question, I found similar question on SO but they do not help in this case.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set difference` of splitted values per rows with `apply`:

```
f=lambda x: ', '.join(set(x['Country'].split(', ')).difference(set(x['Exclude'].split(', '))))
df['Out'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Or list comprehension with `zip`:

```
df['Out'] = ([', '.join(set(a.split(', ')).difference(set(b.split(', ')))) 
                  for a, b in zip(df['Country'], df['Exclude'])])
```

---

```
print (df)
                                  Country         Exclude  \
0  Germany, France, Brazil, India, Russia  France, Brazil   
1   Russia, France, Jamaica, India, China   India, Russia   
2                Germany, Russia, Jamaica         Jamaica   
3                          Italy, Jamaica           Italy   

                      Out  
0  Germany, India, Russia  
1  China, France, Jamaica  
2         Germany, Russia  
3                 Jamaica
```

If order is important:

```
df['Out'] = [', '.join(x for x in a.split(', ') if x not in set(b.split(', '))) 
                    for a, b in zip(df['Country'], df['Exclude'])]
print (df)
                                  Country         Exclude  \
0  Germany, France, Brazil, India, Russia  France, Brazil   
1   Russia, France, Jamaica, India, China   India, Russia   
2                Germany, Russia, Jamaica         Jamaica   
3                          Italy, Jamaica           Italy   

                      Out  
0  Germany, India, Russia  
1  France, Jamaica, China  
2         Germany, Russia  
3                 Jamaica
```

Comment: Awesome!!!, worked like a charm, thanks, this is what exactly required.

Comment: Besides the formatting which is a personal choice (although I do think it's more readable that currently :p) - you don't need to convert `b.split()` into a set as `set.difference` takes any iterable, eg: https://gist.github.com/joncle/ccf9778c5cb42611e822d25e3412ef4c